# Django Group Permission Created view duplicates query

Tags: django

Using simple CreateView:

```
class GroupCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Group
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'group/add.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('group_list')
```

It Creates duplicate query. All getting from permission. How to reduce query

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the template, it looks like you access some related model objects there.

Comment: check updated ques